# When was the last time Anakin fought Dooku prior to RotS?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, anakin-skywalker

I thought this was asked before so I tried to find the question, but couldn't find it so I apologize if this has an answer already.

Anyways, Anakin said to Dooku:

> "My powers have doubled since the last time we fought Count"

Using canon, when was the last time they actually fought? Was Episode two the last time?

Comment: The way obi-wan says this time we will take him together makes it sound like they hadn't fought dooku since episode II, did they forget about fighting him throughout the clone wars

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**CANON:** Anakin fought Dooku last in *The Clone Wars* season 6 episode 10 "The Lost One".

> Anakin and Obi-Wan engage Dooku in combat where they learn that the man called Tyranus is really Count Dooku. Because of this, the Council deduces that Dooku was responsible for the creation of the army. Questioning why their enemy created them an army, Yoda explains that this was really the work of the Dark Lord of the Sith and that all they could do is "play his game".
>   <sub>- [source](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Lost_One)</sub>

[image: gif of lightsaber battle]

[image: lightsabers clashing]

[image: lightsabers clashing]

[image: wider view of the lightsaber battle]

---

<sub>In case of confusion: the fight between Anakin and Dooku that occurred in season 6 episode 13 "[Sacrifice](http://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sacrifice#Plot_Summary)" was actually a just dream-like vision or illusion that happened in Yoda's mind.</sub>

Comment: You had a downvote when you had the "adding to answer later" comment

Comment: @bmarkham Sometimes I have to get the answer out there as fast as possible, you know? lol. I never leave it like that for more than a minute or two. :)

Comment: haha yeah I know. Don't worry, it wasn't me tho.

Comment: That's the downside of Fastest Gun In the West/placeholder posts.

Answer (score 3):

In *Dark Disciple*, a canon book based on unfinished episodes of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, Anakin and Dooku fight while Obi-Wan

> is with Ventress saving Quinlan Vos.

According to the official chronology on starwars.com, this is set after season six. From what we know, this is the last time they fought before *Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith*. Funnily enough, this was pretty far into the last year of the war, so it didn’t take Anakin long to double his powers.

Comment: Anakin was always stuck-up.